# Kolmogorov-Smirnov function

Tags: python, comparative-review, statistics

I'm trying to compare two lists of floating point data and see if they might have come from different underlying distributions. The two samples are a before and after, so by comparing the two I thought I could detect whether any change occurred between the two timeframes.

To do this I'm using the [two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). I have the following function which calculates the core statistic used in the test:

```py
def kolmogorov_smirnov(data1, data2):
    """
    Given two lists of data, finds the two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic
    """
    data1 = sorted(data1)
    data2 = sorted(data2)

    index1 = 0
    index2 = 0

    ks_stat = 0

    while index1 < len(data1) and index2 < len(data2):
        if data1[index1] == data2[index2]:
            index1 += 1
            index2 += 1

        elif data1[index1] < data2[index2]:
            index1 += 1

        elif data1[index1] > data2[index2]:
            index2 += 1

        ks_stat = max(ks_stat, abs(index1/len(data1) - index2/len(data2)))

    return ks_stat
```

I realise that I can also shorten the `while` loop like so:

```py
while index1 < len(data1) and index2 < len(data2):
    if data1[index1] <= data2[index2]:
        index1 += 1

    if data1[index1] >= data2[index2]:
        index2 += 1

    ks_stat = max(ks_stat, abs(index1/len(data1) - index2/len(data2)))
```

Which version should I use? Also, is there anything worth pointing out about the main code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The shorter version seemed better to me at first sight (because it is simpler), but actually it is incorrect. Both `if` statements intend to compare the same two values, but incrementing `index1` changes `data1[index1]` for the second statement. You could fix this by assigning the values to variables:

  ```
  while index1 < len(data1) and index2 < len(data2):
      value1, value2 = data1[index1], data2[index2]
      if value1 <= value2:
          index1 += 1
      if value1 >= value2:
          index2 += 1
  ```
- Updating `ks_stat` one value at a time feels a bit awkward to me. You could collect all the absolute differences in a list and take `max()` of it in the end. Or, extract the loop into a generator to avoid the list.

Comment: Ah, that would have been a very annoying bug to find! I think I'll stick to the first one, because it seems clearer to me now that you've pointed this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert in statistics.

That said, it doesn't look right to throw away the tail of the longer sample (the loop iterates `min(len(data1), len(data2))` times) and at the same time use its length (as in `index1/len(data1)`). For a true K-S test I would expect some sort of interpolation to equalize sample lengths.

Once it is done, you may just reduce the list of absolute differences, along the lines of

```
reduce(lambda x,y: max(x, y), [abs(a - b) for (a,b) in zip(sample1, sample2)], 0)
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as `max(abs(a - b) for (a,b) in zip(sample1, sample2))`?

Comment: Sorry about leaving out the last line of the `while` loop - that was a mistake on my part. I'm not sure I quite follow though - the number of times the loop iterates is dependent on the elements themselves (in the worst case, almost as many iterations as there are elements, e.g. `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]` and `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`). Also, as far as I can tell, the KS test does need both data lists to be equal lengths, which is quite beneficial actually.

Comment: K-S may indeed work with unequal samples, yet it requires interpolation - in other words, where the delta is sampled?

Comment: The tail can be ignored because the maximum absolute difference can't be there. `index1/len(data1)` already equals 1 and `index2/len(data2)` would approach 1 if the iteration went on.